# How to convert bool to NSObject in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios, nsuserdefaults

This is making me a little crazy. I'm trying to register some NSUserDefaults in my MonoTouch app.

```
var defaultsToRegister = new NSMutableDictionary();
defaultsToRegister.SetValueForKey(true, IS_REMINDING);
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.RegisterDefaults(defaultsToRegister);
```

Obviously this isn't compiling because a *bool* cannot be converted to *NSObject*. But when I want to set or retrieve a boolean value from *NSUserDefaults* I can use:

```
public bool IsReminding {
    get {
        return NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.BoolForKey(IS_REMINDING);
    }

    set {
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetBool(value, IS_REMINDING);
    }
}
```

In the settings plist file the boolean is written as `<key>ReminderTimeOfDay</key><true/>` which is what I would expect. So how to register a default boolean value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how I do it:

```
using (var defaults = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys (new object[] {
        true,
    }, new object [] {
        "AllowInternetAccess",
    })) {

    settings.RegisterDefaults (defaults);
}
```

Of course I have more than one key/value pair and this allows me to avoid several calls to a `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 15):

The following worked for me:

```
 bool someValue;
 NSObject objValue = NSObject.FromObject(someValue);
```